# Why this can occure: "failed to open stream: Permission denied/"

Tags: zend-framework, caching, magento

```
 2012-03-21T04:01:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): fopen(/data01/virt32830/domeenid/www.montonfashion.com/htdocs/var/cache/mage--6/mage---internal-metadatas---bee_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalog_product_flat_3_3): failed to open stream: Permission denied/data01/virt32830/domeenid/www.montonfashion.com/htdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php
```

The question is:
Why this situation might occure? 
I clean magento cache before import:

```
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('layout');
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('collections');
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('eav');
```

Then I make import and then clean  cache again.

Previously I'v cleaned cache fully. But I'v got a problem with "100 routing iterations".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to see a change in any these files with the Linux command stat. The syntax is:
$ stat file_name
This command will list the access, the modify and if there is change in file.
This is a way of debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its permissions in the directory. Do `chmod -R 666 /data01/virt32830/domeenid/www.montonfashion.com/htdocs/var/cache/*`

Comment: It could be that the user changed or something. Not sure.

Comment: Very strange, because only I have an access and knowledge of magento on particular server. Therefore I am confused %)

Answer (score 0):

I usually fix permissions problems (and fixed this one) by discovering what is the user and group of my webserver (apache/nginx).
In case of nginx we usually set this group name and user as *nginx*.

So I change the user and group of all folders to it using:

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /path/to/magento
```

If you have multiple users that modifies files there, you can set only the group:

```
chown -R :nginx /path/to/magento
```

I hope it helps.